# Calculate Days between two dates in AIX using Bash

Tags: bash, date, ksh, aix

I am trying to find out the no of days b/w two dates. Below is the code I have which is working perfectly on UNIX.

```
date1=$(date "+%m/%d/%y")
temp1=4/8/24
echo $((($(date -u -d $temp1 +%s) - $(date -u -d $date1 +%s)) / 86400))
```

When I am executing above script on AIX box, I am getting below error:

> date: Not a recognized flag: d
>
> Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
>
> date: Not a recognized flag: d
>
> Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
>
> ( - ) / 86400: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") / 86400")`

It's a PROD env and I don't have admin access to install any pack on it.

Comment: Do you have access to Perl or awk? Take a look: http://unix.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/unixadmin-l/shell-script-to-find-noofdays-between-two-dates-in-aix-server-5591705

Comment: There is awk NOT Gawk on aix box.

Comment: It seems that there's no flag `d` for date on AIX. See information on AIX date commands: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/date.htm

Comment: If you can use perl (and have the module Date installed) this should work  `perl -MDate::Parse -le 'print+(str2time(pop) - str2time(pop)) / 86400' 2016-02-28 2016-03-01`

Comment: Guys, I found out that Perl is there on the server, so I used it to calculate the days. I called the perl prgm in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that a month is 1/12 of a year, and that you use proper 4 digit
years:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function mktm(datespec) {
  split(datespec, q, "/")
  return \
  (q[3] - 1970) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25 + \
  (q[1] -    1) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25 / 12 + \
  (q[2] -    1) * 60 * 60 * 24
}
function ceil(x) {
  y = int(x); return y < x ? y + 1 : y
}
BEGIN {
  srand()
  print ceil((mktm(ARGV[1]) - srand()) / (60 * 60 * 24))
}
```